# Why RestTemplate seems to increment response id?

Tags: kotlin, resttemplate

I have created this integration test with RestTemplate:

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
internal class PatientControllerIntTest @Autowired constructor(
    private val patientRepository: PatientRepository,
    private val restTemplate: TestRestTemplate
) {
private val defaultPatientId = ObjectId.get()

    @LocalServerPort
    protected var port: Int = 0

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        patientRepository.deleteAll()
    }

    private fun getRootUrl(): String = "http://localhost:$port/patients"
    private fun saveOnePatient() = patientRepository.save(Patient(defaultPatientId, "Name", "Description"))

    @Test
    fun `should return single patient by id`() {
        saveOnePatient()

        val response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
            getRootUrl() + "/$defaultPatientId",
            Patient::class.java
        )

        assertEquals(200, response.statusCode.value())
        assertNotNull(response.body)
        assertEquals(defaultPatientId, response.body?.id)
    }
}
```

I have run this application and it responds correctly.

I have debugged it at controller finding the correct id but when I get the response in the test case it is always the expected id incremented by one.

Comment: Do you have the solution for this? I ran into the same issue.

Comment: I don't have. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem by following https://medium.com/techwasti/spring-boot-mongodb-rest-api-using-kotlin-47e49729bb21. When I downgraded kotlin to 1.3.71, everything works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33578273)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem following the mentioned tutorial. When I sent a get request for all entities with curl I recognized, that the id was serialized as an object instead of a string within the json object. After adding a @JsonSerialize annotation to the id the tests worked and the response object showed the id as a string.

Added annotation:

```
@Document()
data class Patient (
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer::class)
    @Id
    val id: ObjectId = ObjectId.get(),
    ...
)
```